# If I fed a dog whole animals, would that be a healthy diet?

Tags: dogs, diet

If I fed a dog complete animals, e.g. freshly put down unskinned rabbits, and let it eat it as it liked, would that be a healthy diet for it or would it need some kind of supplements? And would it know how to handle the fur/skin and avoid to eat maybe the large intestine? The bones?

Comment: I know that when my cats kill and eat mice there's nothing left over. They eat it fur bones intestines and all.

Comment: No, definitely not. Dogs in the wild have a much shorter lifespan than dogs kept as a pet and one good reason is the parasites from the uncooked meat. Unless you have a good reason, just skin, chop and boil the carcass. This is what I do for stray dogs.

Answer (score 4):

There are different aspects to this question.

**Would it be a balanced diet for dogs?**

Probably yes, since dogs evolved from hunters. Though always feeding the same species of animal can slowly lead to an overdose of certain nutrients and a lack of others.

**Would it be healthy?**

Very certainly no. The main problem are parasites like intestinal worms your dog can contract from wild animals. If left untreated, parasites can lead to any number of complications like weight loss, vomiting (many types of worm), bloody diarrhea and internal bleeding (hookworm), anaemia (heartworm), coughing and lack of oxygen (heartworm, lungworm), lethargy and heart failure (final stage of worm infections).

**Would my dog even know how to eat that?**

If the dog was raised with prepared dry or wet food, it probably wouldn't even recognize an animal as "food". However, most dogs react strongly to the smell of blood and raw meat, so they might start eating if the carcass is cut open. In any case, it would need a transition phase to switch from commercial dog food to all raw food. The digestive system and gut microbiome of the dog need some time to get used to the new food.

Comment: Does the disclaimer regarding parasites apply globally? I live in Northern Europe and generally there are very few parasites here, especially not at farms (e.g., although not a parasite, but there are no recommendations agains eating raw eggs (salmonella), no rabies etc).

Comment: Worms live everywhere. But most commercial animals will be treaten against them. Because this kind of worms live inside animals outside temperature is not this important than for other species. And get no recommendations against something does not mean that it is not there ;)

Comment: @d-b There are geological differences in which worms occur where, but as far as I know there is no place in Europe that's completely free of intestinal parasites. The most common worms in Europe are roundworm, lungworm, heartworm and several types of tapeworm. See the [ESCCAP travel advice](https://www.esccap.org/travelling-pets-advice/) for more detailed information.